# Why don't the Nvidia official instructions to install CUDA 11 on Ubuntu 16.04 work?

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, software-installation, cuda, gpu

I am following the [Nvidia official instructions](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads?target_os=Linux&target_arch=x86_64&target_distro=Ubuntu&target_version=1604&target_type=runfilelocal) to install CUDA 11 on Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS x64 don't work:

```
apt-get update && apt-get upgrade 
wget 
http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/11.0.2/local_installers/cuda_11.0.2_450.51.05_linux.run
sudo sh cuda_11.0.2_450.51.05_linux.run
```

During the installation, I kept the default settings:

[image]

I get the following error message:

```
Installation failed. See log at /var/log/cuda-installer.log for details.
```

`/var/log/cuda-installer.log` contains:

```
nano /var/log/cuda-installer.log [INFO]: Driver not installed.
[INFO]: Checking compiler version...
[INFO]: gcc location: /usr/bin/gcc

[INFO]: gcc version: gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.12)

[INFO]: Initializing menu
[INFO]: Setup complete
[INFO]: Components to install:
[INFO]: Driver
[INFO]: 450.51.05
[INFO]: Executing NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.51.05.run --ui=none --no-questions --accept-license --disable-nouveau --no-cc-version-check --install-libglvnd  2>&1
[INFO]: Finished with code: 256
[ERROR]: Install of driver component failed.
[ERROR]: Install of 450.51.05 failed, quitting
```

I also tried the other [Nvidia official instructions](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads?target_os=Linux&target_arch=x86_64&target_distro=Ubuntu&target_version=1604&target_type=deblocal):

```
wget https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1604/x86_64/cuda-ubuntu1604.pin
sudo mv cuda-ubuntu1604.pin /etc/apt/preferences.d/cuda-repository-pin-600
wget http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/11.0.2/local_installers/cuda-repo-ubuntu1604-11-0-local_11.0.2-450.51.05-1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-ubuntu1604-11-0-local_11.0.2-450.51.05-1_amd64.deb
sudo apt-key add /var/cuda-repo-ubuntu1604-11-0-local/7fa2af80.pub
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y install cuda
```

However, this also gives me an error:

```
Processing triggers for ca-certificates (20210119~16.04.1) ...
Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs...
0 added, 0 removed; done.
Running hooks in /etc/ca-certificates/update.d...

done.
done.
Errors were encountered while processing:
 nvidia-450
 nvidia-450-dev
 cuda-drivers-450
 cuda-drivers
 cuda-runtime-11-0
 cuda-demo-suite-11-0
 cuda-11-0
 cuda
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I use Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS x64. `nvidia-smi`:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 440.64.00    Driver Version: 440.64.00    CUDA Version: 10.2     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Tesla V100-SXM2...  On   | 00000000:00:1E.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   34C    P0    23W / 300W |      0MiB / 16160MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

What could be the issue?

Comment: Try the install but unselect the old Nvidia 450 driver.  You probably already have a more current one on your system from the standard repos.  First ensure the Nvidia 460 driver is still working after that failed attempt to install the old driver.  Oops, whatever driver is current for 16.04. (440 you say).

Comment: @ubfan1 Thank you, actually I currently have Driver Version: 440.64.00  +   CUDA Version: 10.2

Answer (score 1):

Run the `NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.51.05.run --ui=none --no-questions --accept-license --disable-nouveau --no-cc-version-check` in Terminal with the driver file to see if the driver alone installs. If so the the additional `--install-libglvnd` is broken. Either way Nvidia needs to be contacted to fix their broken instructions in the package they give for this. They have broken driver or you have incompatible card which causes driver install to fail, or the last part of it is broken the `libglvnd` install. Actually Nvidia only needs to be contacted if it is their problem and not a compatibility problem with your card.

Comment: Thank you, Executing the command `sudo sh cuda_11.0.2_450.51.05_linux.run --ui=none --no-questions --accept-license --disable-nouveau --no-cc-version-check` gives the error  `Unknown option: --ui=none`.

Comment: It is the `NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.51.05.run` you need to do with that command.

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to install from Ubuntu Recovery mode.

Boot into GRUB menu and select Recovery -> select "root" in Recovery Menu -> From the terminal, run cuda_11.3.1_465.19.01_linux.run (your version varies)

Make sure your card is supported by the driver.

After installed, I had to do a re-link to run cuda programs:

```
$ ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1.7.0 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so
```

Driver status:

```
$ nvidia-smi
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 465.19.01    Driver Version: 465.19.01    CUDA Version: 11.3     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA T400         Off  | 00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| 38%   40C    P8    N/A /  31W |    181MiB /  1867MiB |      3%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
```

My system is Ubuntu 16 with customized kernel 4.15.18:

```
$ uname -a
Linux np1 4.15.18-cma #1 SMP Tue May 17 13:07:31 PDT 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```